# Was working on a sample question of an old JAVA book, I have posted my answer just not sure about it. Could someone verify if answer is true

Tags: java

Below is an implementaton of `specificTypeAverage(TransactionType specificType)`. Read through it carefully

```
public double specificTypeAverage(TransactionType specificType) {
    double totalCost = 0;
    int numTransactions = 0;
    for (Transaction t : transactions) {
        if (t.getType().equals(specificType)) {
            totalCost += t.getAmount();
            numTransactions++;
        }
    }
    return totalCost / numTransactions;
}
```

Which of the following describes the best set of unit tests for the `specificTypeAverage()` method?. Select the set of tests from the options with the best code coverage:

a)

- One test where transactions is empty
- A second test where transactions has one transaction of the specified type.

b)

- One test where transactions is empty
- A second test where transactions is non-empty but contains no  transactions of the specified type
- A third test where transactions only contains one transaction of the
  specified type.

c)

- One test where transactions is non-empty but contains no transactions
  of the specified type
- A second test where transactions contains at least 2 transactions of
  the specified type.

d)

- One test where transactions is empty
- A second test where transactions contains at least 2 transactions of the specified type.

**I believe the answer is b)** because it also accounts for the transaction being empty and non-empty.

What is your opinion on my answer if you belive it's wrong could tell me which choice you would choose and why, thanks.

Comment: I would say `b` since it covers the two tests which could result in division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Choice B will test all branches except bad input. The first test will result in an ArithmeticException. Looking at the code, I'm assuming that `transactions` is at the instance level. That is not a good practice, because while you iterate through the list, some other thread could change the `transactions` state.

A better method signature could be -

```
public double specificTypeAverage(List<Transaction> transactions, TransactionType specificType)
```

also, you could add a line at the beginning of the method to avoid `ArithmeticException`.

```
if(transactions.isEmpty()) {
   return 0;
}
```

Another good practice is to keep the constant/enum on the left side of the equals to avoid NullPointerException.

```
if (specificType.equals(t.getType())
```

If TransactionType is an enum, you could use `==` instead of `equals()`

Answer (score 0):

*Opinion:* I would say **`c`**.

- *"Empty"* is a special case of *"no match"*, so there is no need to test both.
- *"1 transaction"* is similar to *"at least 2"*. Both test the filtering, assuming transactions has transactions of other types, but *"1 transaction"* doesn't fully test the average calculation.
- Since we need the *"at least 2"* test, for the testing of the average calculation, it must be `c` or `d`.
- Since *"no match"* is a better test than *"empty"*, the choice is **`c`**.

---

<sup>Abbreviations used above:

*"empty":* test where transactions is empty

*"no match":* test where transactions is non-empty but contains no transactions of the specified type

*"only 1":* test where transactions only contains one transaction of the specified type

*"at least 2":* test where transactions contains at least 2 transactions of the specified type</sup>